# reCaptcha V2 is now timing out during valication

Tags: recaptcha

I have been using reCaptcha V2 for awhile now and all of a sudden the validation is timing out on the file_get_contents line.

I can copy the URL from the error and paste it into a new window and the JSON object comes back immediately.

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='. urlencode($secret) .'&response='. urlencode($captcha);
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
```

Comment: I have increased the timeout for the file_get_contents to 120 seconds.  After 60 seconds, the recaptcha expires and I have to click the checkbox again.  Then 20 seconds later it passes recaptcha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this timeout problem with the File_get_contents by changing to using $curl instead.

Like this:

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($secret) .  '&response=' . urlencode($captcha);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
// file get contents not used any more
//$response = file_get_contents($url,0,stream_context_create(["http"=>["timeout"=>120]]) );
$responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
// should return JSON with success as true
```